# How to import default Grails tag library into JSON Views

Tags: json, grails, groovy

The new features for Grails JSON Views are great, but it would be super handy to access all the grails tag libraries in JSON Views. For instance I would like to access the formatDate tag for formatting my dateOfBirth field like so:

```
model {
    Person person
}
json {
    id person.id
    displayName person.displayName
    dateOfBirth g.formatDate(date: person?.dateOfBirth, format: 'dd-MM-yyyy')
}
```

The benefit of using the formatDate tag is that I can leverage the default date format and also import date format properties without extraneous code.

I am using Grails 3.2.0 and Views 1.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag libraries are a feature of GSP, which is view rendering technology designed primarily to render markup defined as tags (HTML, XML etc.).

JSON views are designed to render JSON, hence support for tag libraries (i.e. tags) makes no sense, since tags don't exist in JSON.

Comment: Fair point. I guess my intention was to be able to access some formatting logic in a standardised way. I thought that because g.render and g.link were available in JSON Views that maybe there was a way to access other other tag like functions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work,

```
person?.dateOfBirth?.format('dd-MM-yyyy')
```

See here, [Groovy Docs, Date.format(String format)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Yes it does work, but I was just providing this as an example. I want to be able to access the Grails tag libraries in JSON Views ultimately. If I can add my own tag libraries as well, like I can with GSP views then I could add all sorts of custom formatting logic.

Comment: I don't see the benefit, especially, when one can call functions in there.